# Remove Part of an NSString and copy it into another NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, substring, nsrange

So I have an NSString, lets say it: `NSString *mainString = @"My Name is Andrew (I like computers)";`
And I want remove everything from the "(" to the ")" from mainString.  And I want to put everything in between the "()" into a subString.

For example:

```
NSString *mainString = @"My Name is Andrew (I like computers)";
NSString *subString;

//The code I need help with

mainString = @"y Name is Andrew ";
subString = @"I like computers";
```

I hope this makes sense.  It would really help me.  Thanks in Advance.  I've been playing with `NSRange` and `NSMutableStrings` but I'm having trouble.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably an easier way:

```
NSString *mainString = @"My Name is Andrew (I like computers)";
NSString *subString;

NSArray *array = [mainString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"]];

mainString = [array objectAtIndex:0]; // "My Name is Andrew "
subString = [array objectAtIndex:1]; // "I like computers"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I just realized I just used this code for probably the 10th time.  It really helped me

Answer (score 9):

```
int startPosition = [mainString rangeOfString:@"("].location + 1;
int endPosition   = [mainString rangeOfString:@")"].location;

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition);

NSString *subString = [mainString substringWithRange:range];
```

and as  darvids0n has mentioned in below comment:

```
    mainString = [mainString substringToIndex:startPosition - 1]
```

Comment: And then `string = [string substringToIndex:startPosition - 1]`.

Comment: no we created range in such a way that it will take care of the ")". so substringtoindex: is not required here